# Dragged ImageView, knowing when it's in an X Y area

Tags: android, imageview, drag, region

I have a draggable image and I'm trying to get it so that if it goes within an X Y region of the screen that an event happens.

So far I can detect when I move a finger through the region but not when it is dragging the image.

*The code so far:* - this code works for the finger

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    int x = (int) ev.getX();
    int y = (int) ev.getY();
    switch (ev.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (x >= 370 && x <= 500 && y >= 250 && y <= 420) {
            Log.i(null, "--- Region 1 initiated ---");
        }
```

*What I've tried:* - but when I try to adapt it to the image...

```
public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {

    int action = dragevent.getAction();

    View getid = findViewById(R.id.image);
    int x1 = (int) getid.getX();
    int y1 = (int) getid.getY();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (x1 >= 370 && x1 <= 500 && y1 >= 250 && y1 <= 420) {
            Log.i(null, "--- Region 1 initiated by image---");

        }
    }
```

...nothing happens. The logcat doesn't show the message. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong or if there's a way of doing this.

Some illustrations, sometimes my description of the problem is pretty bad:

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while but I actually got it working by doing this in onTouch:

```
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    ImageView j = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

 switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        _xDelta = (int) (X - j.getTranslationX());
        _yDelta = (int) (Y - j.getTranslationY());
        break;

  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        _xDelta = 100;
        _yDelta = 100;
        break;

  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        j.setTranslationX(X - _xDelta);
        j.setTranslationY(Y - _yDelta);
        if (X >= 370 && X <= 500 && Y >= 250 && Y <= 420) {
            Log.i(null, "Region 1 initiated");
            // Do whatever...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE defined in DragEvent class

OnDragListener interface defined the method

```
abstract boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
```

Action are:

- ACTION_DRAG_STARTED
- ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED
- ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION
- ACTION_DRAG_EXITED
- ACTION_DROP
- ACTION_DRAG_ENDED

Please refer to this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) for more details

Comment: Why doesn't it throw an error? I was wondering why it was working alright, I figured if there was no error or warning that it was included somehow.

Comment: Also I tried various `ACTION_DR...` and couldn't get it working